# SSD "broke" and now shows up in Disk Management as not initialized

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, ssd, crash

My friend was playing a game the other day when his computer randomly crashed. After attempting to restart, he got the "Reboot and Select proper Boot device" blackscreen. His SSD showed up in the BIOS, but could not be booted from. I stuck it into my computer, and ran diskpart. `list disk` listed it once, after which subsequent `list disk`s did not. Right now, the it shows up as "Not Initialized" and "20 MB Unallocated" in Disk Management.

Is there any chance of returning the SSD to its state before the crash? Do I have to reformat it (there wasn't much on it, but it would be nice not to lose everything)? Or is it completely broken, and he needs to buy a new one?

Comment: 20MB unallocated. This suggests the controller is unable to communicate with the NAND. The drive has failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not specified the make and model of the disk, but the short answer is most likely no.  This is a classical failure mode for many SSD's -  it might be possible (but not cheap) for a specialist firm to recover the data, but this requires physically removing chips off the board.

Google SSD sudden death for more on the topic.

Comment: You're lucky the SSD failed in an obvious way.  I had one that failed only for write operations.  Wasted 6 hours trying to figure out why, because Windows will just blue screen instead of telling you it is having write errors.  A Linux boot disc told me the drive failed to write.

Comment: Yeah, this appears to be the case. Luckily it's under a 3 year warranty, so he's getting a new one soon.